# remove file from input type file multiple

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I`m building little plugin for file uploads

this is my fiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/giasoft/6gkosyvj/
```

I have problem on remove button
when I click
I need to remove file from input type file
but I can not read length

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem.
I create object and removing from it

and before send submit
I render textarea with looping this object and add the contents...

so now I`m getting base64 string on server and the problem was resolver...